# C++ Undefined abstract class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, segmentation-fault, abstract-class

I've been having a bit of trouble lately in C++ with virtual methods/inheritance

At first if i try to extend a super class i get this error:

> 'Undefined reference to GameState::GameState()'

but if i remove the constructors all together i don't get the above error but i end up with a segmentation fault which occurs when calling the virtual method.

This is my code:

```
#ifndef GAMESTATE_H
#define GAMESTATE_H

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Resources.h"
#include "Renderer.h"

class GameState {
public:
    GameState();
    virtual void init(Resources *res) = 0;
    virtual void exit() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void render(Renderer *renderer) = 0;
};

#endif // GAMESTATE_H
```

and this is the subclass:

```
#include "GameState.h"

class MainGameState : public GameState {
public:
    MainGameState() : GameState() {

    }

    virtual void init(Resources *res) {

    }

    virtual void update() {
        printf("test\n");
    }

    virtual void render(Renderer *renderer) {

    }

    virtual void exit() {

    }
private:
    SDL_Surface *image;
};
```

Comment: And where did you define `GameState::GameState`?

Comment: How are you using these classes

Comment: Maybe post an example call. Also you could try asking valgrind what gives the segmentation fault

Comment: Your first error is because the abstract class GameState does not give a definition to its constructor, but the MainGameState constructor calls it.  Just changing `GameState();` to `GameState() { }` would fix that.  We could be more help with the second if you told us which virtual method you're calling before the segfault.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
GameState() { }
```

instead of

```
GameState();
```

or define it somewhere else.

Though, I'm not sure if it has anything to do with virtual methods. I think there's a bug elsewhere. Perhaps, uninitialized pointer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an implementation for the constructor if you want to explicitly call it:

```
class GameState {
public:
    GameState() {} // implementation
    virtual void init(Resources *res) = 0;
    virtual void exit() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void render(Renderer *renderer) = 0;
};
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't put a semicolon there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete program which implements the base and derived classes you are looking for. You receive the linker error message because you never implemented `GameState::GameState`. It isn't clear why you got the segmentation fault.

Remember also, if you want to delete your objects polymorphically, declare and define a virtual base-class destructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#define X() (std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n")
class GameState {
public:
  GameState() { X(); }
  virtual ~GameState() { X(); }
  virtual void F() = 0;
};

class MainGameState : public GameState {
public:
  MainGameState() : GameState() { X(); }
  void F() { X(); }
  ~MainGameState() { X(); }
};

int main () {
  GameState* pGS = new MainGameState;
  X();
  pGS->F();
  delete pGS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The compiler will call a parameterless base class constructor (default constructor) for you anyway, so it is unnecessary.  However, are you even providing a definition for `GameState::GameState()`?  Probably not, so you should just get rid of it or provide an implementation (i.e., `GameState() { }`).
2. We need to see how you are calling the function.  That looks fine to me, your bug is somewhere else.  Are you perhaps declaring a pointer to an object, not initializing it, and then calling `update()`?

If I have to guess (and apparently I do...) I would bet that you have something like this:

```
MainGameState *state;
state->update();  // oops!  Not initialize!
```

Of course I may be wrong, but like I said, I am forced to guess until you update your question with the real code.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Haha yeah I know, that was a mental blip.  I go between C# and C++ so often that I sometimes confuse the syntax between the two.  I edited that out before you posted the comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, the term is 'default constructor'. You probably know that already and I'm guessing you used parameterless so it's easier for the op to understand.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yes, I know, and a default constructor is parameterless.

Comment: :) I figured that. I just pressed enter key before I was done writing the whole comment :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yeah, you're right though; it doesn't hurt to use common language when talking to a relative beginner as to save them some confusion in the future.  I just wish I could see how he is calling the function that is faulting...

Answer (score 0):

This error `'Undefined reference to GameState::GameState()'` tells you that GameState constructor isn't defined. It has nothing to do with virtual method.

Do what @Luchian and @Micheal said:

```
class GameState {
public:
    GameState() {} // implementation
```

If it was a virtual method error, you would get something like `"the 'MainGameState' must implement inherited pure virtual method 'method name'"`

**EDIT:** Note that the super class constructor is implicitly called when you instantiate a sub-class.